# Virtualbox bridged network not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running the most recent virtual box and created a Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine. It works with NAT networking, but when I switch to bridged I get the following error:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine class. Failed to
>   open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-Realtek PCIe
>   GBE Family Controller' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND). Failed to
>   attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Anyone have any idea how to solve this, I tried to re-install Virtual Box, and I tried to install on a different computer but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "${VB_VM_NAME}" --nic${NCARD} \
    bridged --bridgeadapter${NCARD} ${VB_VM_HOST_NET_ADAPTER}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get bridged networking working below are the set of commands:

```
NCARD=2 # Corresponds to eth1 on Guest (change accordingly)
VB_VM_HOST_NET_ADAPTER="eth0" # Host network adapter
VBoxManage modifyvm "${VB_VM_NAME}" --nic${NCARD} \
 bridged --bridgeadapter${NCARD} ${VB_VM_HOST_NET_ADAPTER}
```

Ref: http://virtualbox.guru